# How can multiple services interact remotely to ensure normal flow

Tags: java, spring, sockets, resttemplate

everyone. I have a problem. Can you help me? Thanks

**Background:**

Server A communicates with server B by RESTTemplate, and server B communicates with client C by socket
The whole process is basically as follows: C makes A request, goes to A, and returns the result to C:
C-->B-->A-->B-->C
There is also the following business
A-->B-->C-->B-->A

**Question:**

ABC is a remote call, there are always some accidents in the middle (such as C sent a request, C hung or network timeout, C could not receive the message, that is, C-->B-->A-->B-->C), how to ensure the occurrence of unexpected circumstances, but also to let the business closed loop
Is there a mature plan?

**My try:**

I tried to save the state in B, and then let C request it again and decide which step to continue according to the situation, but I felt it was too cumbersome to do so, and I didn't know if there was any other plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use-case is a common problem in business transactions which span multiple services and because of distributed nature there could be many failure scenarios which are out of service control like network issues, latencies, unexpected failures. There are several techniques and the most commonly used is [Compensating transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/compensating-transaction) by using Eventual consistency  or [Saga](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/01/patterns-for-distributed-transactions-within-a-microservices-architecture/) pattern

Comment: Thank you. My projects are B, a and C projects of other companies. If we can't adopt distributed projects, are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microservices with Spring to get loosely coupled processes.
It can perform continuous delivery of a large and complex application.

You can refer to [Microservices with Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring)